Errors while implementing JWT Authentication in Spring Boot App | 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found
I'm trying to implement JWT auth in spring boot application, but facing some errors. Please help.
Errors and logs at the end of this doc
This is my security config class
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;



    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager theUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        theUserDetailsManager
                .setUsersByUsernameQuery("select user_email, user_password, enabled from chat_user where user_email=?");

        theUserDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_email, authority from authorities where user_email=?");
        return theUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer -> configurer
                        .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll() //initially non authenticated users does not have access to css, so this is added
                        .requestMatchers("/showSignUpForm","/showLoginForm","/processSignUpForm").permitAll() // allow unauthenticated access to sign up page
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                        .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/showLoginForm")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                        .usernameParameter("user_email")
                        .passwordParameter("user_password")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/showChatPage", true)
                        .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration auth) throws Exception {
        return auth.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

This is my controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
@Slf4j
public class PublicController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private ChatUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @GetMapping("/health-check")
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "Ok";
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public void signup(@RequestBody ChatUser user) {
        userService.saveChatUser(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody ChatUser user) {
        try{
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUser_email(), user.getUser_password()));
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUser_email());
            String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails.getUsername());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jwt, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Exception occurred while createAuthenticationToken ", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Incorrect username or password", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}

This is my JwtFilter class
@Component
public class JwtFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }
        if (username != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

This is my UserDetailsServiceImpl class
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private ChatUserService chatUserService;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ChatUser user = chatUserService.findByUserEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                    .username(user.getUser_email())
                    .password(user.getUser_password())
                    .roles("ROLE_USER")
                    .build();
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + email);
    }
}

ChatUserService interface
public interface ChatUserService {
    
    public List<ChatUser> getChatUsers();

    public void saveChatUser(ChatUser theChatUser);
    
    public ChatUser getChatUser(int theId);

    public void deleteChatUser(int theId);
    
    public ChatUser findByUsername(String username);
    
    public ChatUser findByUserEmail(String email);
    
}

ChatUserServiceImpl

@Service
public class ChatUserServiceImpl implements ChatUserService{

    @Autowired
    private ChatUserDAO chatUserDao;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthorityDAO authorityDao;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<ChatUser> getChatUsers() {
        return chatUserDao.getchatUsers();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveChatUser(ChatUser theChatUser) {
        chatUserDao.saveChatUser(theChatUser);
        // Create and save the Authority
        Authority authority = new Authority(theChatUser.getUser_email(), "ROLE_USER");
        authorityDao.saveOrUpdateAuthority(authority);

        // Add the Authority to the ChatUser
        theChatUser.getAuthorities().add(authority);
  
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ChatUser getChatUser(int theId) {
        return chatUserDao.getChatUser(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteChatUser(int theId) {
        chatUserDao.deleteChatUser(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ChatUser findByUsername(String username) {
        return chatUserDao.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ChatUser findByUserEmail(String email) {
        return chatUserDao.findByUserEmail(email);
    }
    

}

Similar interface for ChatUserDAO
My ChatUserDAOImpl class looks like this which is using hibernate session factory

@Repository
public class ChatUserDAOImpl implements ChatUserDAO{
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<ChatUser> getchatUsers() {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<ChatUser> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from ChatUser", ChatUser.class);
        List<ChatUser> chatUsers = theQuery.getResultList();
        return chatUsers;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void saveChatUser(ChatUser theChatUser) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theChatUser);   
    }

    @Override
    public ChatUser getChatUser(int theId) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ChatUser theChatUser = currentSession.get(ChatUser.class, theId);
        return theChatUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteChatUser(int theId) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("delete from ChatUser where chat_id=:chatUserId");
        theQuery.setParameter("chatUserId", theId);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public ChatUser findByUsername(String username) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<ChatUser> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from ChatUser where user_name=:u", ChatUser.class);
        theQuery.setParameter("u", username);
        try {
            return theQuery.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ChatUser findByUserEmail(String email) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<ChatUser> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from ChatUser where user_email=:e", ChatUser.class);
        theQuery.setParameter("e", email);
        try {
            return theQuery.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

When i'm trying to run the app, i'm getting this error
Description:
Field userDetailsService in com.springprojects.realtimechatapp.filter.JwtFilter required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- userDetailsServiceImpl: defined in file [C:...\service\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]
- userDetailsManager: defined by method 'userDetailsManager' in class path resource [com/springprojects/.../SecurityConfig.class]
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
What I tried
@Primary is not allowed on UserDetailsServiceImpl instance in security class. I tried @Primary on UserDetailsManager but now it gives me this error:
Description:
Field sessionFactory in com.springprojects.realtimechatapp.dao.ChatUserDAOImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.
I'm confused about how to use one of them.
Try 2: (failed)
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springprojects.realtimechatapp")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


//    @Bean
//    public DataSource getDataSource() {
//        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
//        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
//        dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
//        dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
//        dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
//        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
//        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
//        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
//        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.springprojects.realtimechatapp" });
//        return sessionFactory;
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
//        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
//        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
//        return txManager;
//    }
//

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    
    
    //Cannot instantiate SessionFactory
//    @Bean 
//    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
//      return new SessionFactory();
//  } 
//    
}


If you open java docs of UserDetailsManager you will see that it extends UserDetailsService and you also have your own implementation UserDetailsServiceImpl, this is the reason why you get: Field userDetailsService in com.springprojects.realtimechatapp.filter.JwtFilter required a single bean, but 2 were found:
And based on it I suggest you to get rid of UserDetailsManager from your SecurityConfig class and keep UserDetailsService that you have already added it.
For more details and also what is the difference in using UserDetailsManager or own implementation of UserDetailsService you will be able to find out in this answer using-jdbcuserdetailsmanager-vs-own-userdetailsservice

Yes, I tried removing UserDetailsManager but then i get this error mentioned in original question.
Field sessionFactory in com.springprojects.realtimechatapp.dao.ChatUserDAOImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

Do you have spring-data-jpa dependency declared in your pom.xml or gradle build file ?

Because SessionFactory is an hibernate staff and hibernate is ORM under spring data jpa, or you have to create it manually as a @Bean

yes i have this dependency in my pom.xml.  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Just create @Bean public SessionFactory getSessionFactory {return new SessionFactory()} it should help in your case

I tried this, and similar approaches too, but to no good. Updated original question.

Also provide the error that you get when you are creating the SessionFactory @Bean
